# Configuring access to my SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to link my SQL Server with C#, but l got an error saying

> Warning
>   The element 'configSections' has invalid child element 'connectionStrings'. List of possible elements expected: 'section, sectionGroup'.

Would like to know how I can deal with this problem, thanks.

This is my config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="ConString" connectionString="Data Source=BOY-PC;Initial   Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True"
           providerName="System.Data.sqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
  </configSections>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't put your connection strings inside a config section - use this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <configSections />
   <connectionStrings>
      <add name="ConString" 
           connectionString="Data Source=BOY-PC;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True"
           providerName="System.Data.sqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Your node `<connectionStrings>` must be directly under `<configuration>` (not inside `<configSections>` - that node is used to define new, custom configuration sections - that's not necessary here, `<connectionStrings>` is a system-defined configuration section)

Answer (score 0):

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <configSections />
   <connectionStrings>
      <add name="ConString" 
           connectionString="Data Source=BOY-PC;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True"
           providerName="System.Data.sqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```